# How to make an array sum of month from Postgresql query to Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-postgresql, pg

I'm new in programming but here's the thing: I'm trying to make rails app which takes data from postgresql database and shows summary in jqPlot chart, but I am having trouble with my queries. I need an array for the chart which would be formatted something like this total_durations=[["Jan", 3456],["Feb", 21], etc]

Here's the table called **usagedata** in my db:

```
╔═══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║   record_id   ║   user_id   ║     submit_time     ║   duration     ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║             1 ║           6 ║ 2012-09-19 22:18:58 ║      45        ║
║             2 ║           1 ║ 2012-09-19 22:45:59 ║      0         ║
║             3 ║           5 ║ 2012-09-20 01:57:52 ║      3987      ║
║             4 ║           8 ║ 2012-09-18 03:47:53 ║      34        ║
║             5 ║           9 ║ 2013-01-26 20:38:03 ║      678       ║
║             6 ║           1 ║ 2013-01-26 23:41:44 ║      56        ║
║             7 ║           2 ║ 2013-01-27 02:10:41 ║      100       ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

**1. Partial Method**
I have Model usagedata.rb:

```
class Usagedata < ActiveRecord::Base     
  def self.by_month     
   h = Usagedata.calculate(:sum, :duration, :conditions => {     
     :submit_time => (Time.now.all_year) },    
     :order => "EXTRACT(month FROM submit_time)",     
     :group => ["EXTRACT(month FROM submit_time)","EXTRACT(year FROM submit_time)"])  

  end 
end
```

controller usagedata_controller.rb:

```
class UsagedataController < ApplicationController     
    def index    
    end
    private
    def set_usagedata
      @usagedata = Usagedata.find(params[:id])
    end
    def usagedata_params
      params[:usagedata]
    end
end
```

And view **index.html.haml**:

```
%br=h = Usagedata.by_month
```

Output of the view is:

```
{[1.0, 2013.0]=>135776897, [2.0, 2013.0]=>100620585, [3.0, 2013.0]=>162980319, [4.0, 2013.0]=>26916589, [5.0, 2013.0]=>18793323, [6.0, 2013.0]=>9250440, [7.0, 2013.0]=>5011563, [12.0, 2012.0]=>24092}
```

How can I get an array `total_durations=[["Jan", 3456],["Feb", 21], etc]` according to the database table where month is taken from submit_time field and the other number is sum of durations made each month. Or even array like `total_durations=[["1.0, 2013.0", 135776897],["2.0, 2013.0", 100620585], etc]` would help.

**2. Partial method** 
I managed to get output what I needed in db:

```
select to_char(submit_time,'Mon') as mon,
   extract(year from submit_time) as yyyy,
   sum("duration") as "Total_Duration"
from usagedata
group by 1,2
```

but how can I get the output of the query to array in Rails?

I've tried this in my html.haml page:

```
%br=Usagedata.select("duration, extract (month from submit_time) as month, extract(year from submit_time) as year, SUM(submit_time) as total").group(1,2)
```

But it's just printing line:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Usagedata:0x007f1c10997518>
```

Also tried to add it to my controller as:

```
@fetch = []
  Usagedata.select("extract (month from submit_time) as month, extract(year from submit_time) as year, SUM(duration)").group_by(1,2).each do |ph|
    @fetch << [ph.month.to_f, ph.year, ph.sum]
end
```

But this is just giving me an error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR: column "usagedata.submit_time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT extract (month from submit_time) as month, extract(ye... ^ : SELECT extract (month from submit_time) as month, extract(year from submit_time) as year, SUM(duration) FROM "usagedata"
```

**3. Partial Method**
Discribed here: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=27205

controller.rb:

```
    @usagedata_groups = Usagedata.find(:all,
    :select => 'submit_time, wall_duration, id', 
    :conditions => {:machine_name_id => ["1"]},).group_by{|usagedata| usagedata.submit_time.beginning_of_month}

    @fetch = []
    Usagedata.find(:all,
    :select => 'submit_time, wall_duration, id', 
    :conditions => {:machine_name_id => ["1"]},).group_by{|usagedata| usagedata.submit_time.beginning_of_month}.keys.sort.each do |month|
       @fetch << month.strftime("%B %Y")
       @fetch << month.collect(&:wall_duration).sum
    end
```

index.html.haml

```
  %table
    %tr         
     %th    
     - @usagedata_groups.keys.sort.each do |month|        
       %tr
        %td
          #{month.strftime("%B %Y")}          
        %td
          #month.collect(&:wall_duration).sum 
  %table
    %tr
     %th Show @fetch content:    
     - @fetch.each do |co|
       %tr 
        %td=co
```

Output without the line `@fetch << month.collect(&:wall_duration).sum` in controller:

```
February 2013     98503443
March 2013            162980319
April 2013            26916589
May 2013              18793323
June 2013             9250440
July 2013             5399525

Show @fetch content
February 2013
March 2013
April 2013
May 2013
June 2013
July 2013
```

with that line I get an error:

```
NoMethodError in UsagedataController#index
undefined method `collect' for Fri, 01 Feb 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00:Time
```

Please help!

Comment: It doesn't look like you will get any better performance, the query is fine. However, if you want to use Rails ActiveRecord for convenience, go ahead. You have all the information you need here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: You might obtain better performance if you parse dates and sum duration in ruby, instead.

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc I've edited my post for futher instructions. I can't seem to find the way to make query into right array now. :/

Comment: Can't look at it now, I'll later. However, NEVER access the DB from the view, that's what the controller is for. Do that query in the controller, save theresult in an instance variable and then access it from the view.

Comment: @DamienRoche: I doubt there would be better performance parsing and summing dates in memory, as opposed to having the database do it

Comment: For your first part: `{[1.0, 2013.0]=>135776897, [2.0, 2013.0]=>100620585, [3.0, 2013.0]=>162980319, [4.0, 2013.0]=>26916589, [5.0, 2013.0]=>18793323, [6.0, 2013.0]=>9250440, [7.0, 2013.0]=>5011563, [12.0, 2012.0]=>24092}` You can do: `{[1.0, 2013.0]=>135776897, [2.0, 2013.0]=>100620585, [3.0, 2013.0]=>162980319, [4.0, 2013.0]=>26916589, [5.0, 2013.0]=>18793323, [6.0, 2013.0]=>9250440, [7.0, 2013.0]=>5011563, [12.0, 2012.0]=>24092}.map{ |k,v| [k.join(', '), v] }` which should give the desire result.

Comment: And as @Hallucynogenyc mentioned, please do not make database queries in views, do not even write them in controllers. Write such db queries in models, and then use model's method to fetch the data, assign it with a variable then use that variable in the view. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#load data in struct like this
# ["2"=>100620585, "3"=>135776897]
items = Usagedata
          .where(submit_time: Time.now.all_year)
          .order('EXTRACT(month FROM submit_time)')
          .group('EXTRACT(month FROM submit_time)')
          .sum(:duration)

# and regroup it right way
# [["2", 100620585], ["3", 135776897]]
result = items.map { |month, sum| [month, sum] }
```